# What does a simple or a complex substituent mean?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

I am reading rules for IUPAC Nomenclature. The following statement is from my book.

> Prefixes di, tri, tetra, etc., are not considered in deciding alphabetical order for simple substituents but considered for complex substituents.

With respect to the above statement, what does a simple or a complex substituent mean? Could you please give any examples of simple and complex substituents. How to decide whether a substituent is simple or complex? Is there any rule to decide that?

Comment: Please give an actual problem you find difficult. Your textbook might explain things correctly or not, we can only put it to the test if we have a test.

Comment: @Karl, I am having doubt in determining which groups are called complex. Is that based on the number of carbon atoms, or number of substituents, etc. If it is based on number of substituents, in the group under consideration, what is the minimum number of substituents in the group to make it complex. Since simple and complex are relative terms, I didn't get which groups are simple and which ones are complex.